# How can I convince my manager not to give up on MVC to get back to Web Forms?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, webforms, comparison

I work in a company where, since I arrived, I had full freedom to use whatever Microsoft technology, pattern and tool in order to develop my applications.

I started to develop all the applications with **ASP.NET MVC3** and I currently have 5 applications **deployed and working**.

The other day I had a meeting with my manager to review all the applications and he realized that my code was completely different than what he expected. He basically realized that **I do not use Web Forms** and that **I use MVC** instead. He thought he was just some component/tool and not a totally different **approach to programming**. He was curious and he briefly studied what ASP.NET MVC was.

After two days he said that I need to convert all the applications to **Web Forms** and use just Web Forms from now on. He says that **MVC** resembles the old **asp**(that for certain aspects is true) and that it takes **longer time** to develop the application and makes people **confused** when there is the need to **change/maintain** the application.

I think it is not true because, after a steep beginning, I got used to the magic of MVC and it eases development, componentization and maintenance of applications.

I said him that **Web Forms** is **too coupled UI/Logic/DAL**, after a while the code becomes **unreadable** and it **jeopardizes unit testing**. I also shown the possibility to replace the old **GridView**(one of his main concerns) with the **jQuery or MVCContrib** grids.

There was no way to convince him. Both for work and personal development I do not want to take a step back to Web Forms, therefore I kindly ask you to tell me  the most important points that make MVC "superior" to Web Forms.

Thanks

Comment: Wait, you were told to **rewrite working applications** because he doesn't like the framework used? *Seriously?* Even leaving aside the part where Web Forms is utter garbage and ASP.NET MVC is just an attempt to catch up with actual modern technology, pointless rewrites are just absurd. Your manager is grossly incompetent. I suggest looking for a new job.

Comment: I think this question belongs to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Your manager HAS to consider the skill sets of the development teams he/she employs that will have to maintain the code after you have gone. This isn't about you it's about business. Don't waste your time, move on to another role or bite the bullet.

Comment: @jamesw: No, if the manager is demanding a rewrite of working code it's almost certainly not about business, it's about the manager himself. Sudden rewrites to change technology platforms are almost never reasonable from a business standpoint.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it's not uncommon for a manager to give a business-speak-laden version of "I don't understand this, so I want you to do it my way instead."  This often stifles progress.  (I've actually left jobs in the past for this very reason, managers who refused to allow any development that they personally didn't design.)

However, you also need to keep an open mind on the subject.  He may very well have good reasons for this.  Supporting the code is a big concern, and while I agree that it's easier to write clean and de-coupled code in MVC, at the same time he might be seeing a market where it's much easier/cheaper to hire farmed out developers at low cost to support a WebForms application.  He may have a stack of resumes in his drawer that paint a very different picture between WebForms and MVC.

The best thing you can do, really, is approach both paradigms with a completely open mind.  Understand that the rumors of WebForms' demise are greatly exaggerated.  So if you really want to convince him of anything, then you're going to have to present a proper and unbiased comparison.

Start with a simple pros and cons list to compare the two paradigms.  Make sure you don't skip on anything.  If he has pros for WebForms and cons for MVC that you tried to ignore, that'll hurt your case.  Evolve that list into some examples, demonstrations, proofs of concepts, etc.  Make your argument tactile, give it numbers and tangible values that mean something real to management beyond just "this is a better development strategy."  Quantify it.

If you approach this with an argument that says little more than "well, my way is better because it just is" then you're not going to get far.  Even if you have a point to make, you have to successfully make that point to him.  You have to put it in his language.

This is really less about which development strategy is better and more about communication and clarifying your ideas.  After all, if you can't defend your position then from his perspective it's not a good position.

And if you fully clarify and quantify all of this, and it's critical that you keep an open mind about WebForms, then what you've done is given him the information he needs to make an informed decision.  That decision may not change.  He may still insist on WebForms.  But it's his decision.  What you're doing here is presenting him with all the pros and cons, all the costs and benefits (both immediate and long-term in terms of re-writing what you already have and ongoing support and all of that).  If his decision turns out to be wrong, at least it will have been his informed decision.  You won't have kept anything from him.

In the end, he may still insist that you do things the way he understands them.  Some managers are like that.  But take this as an opportunity for your career to master the art of presenting an argument.  It won't be the last time you find yourself doing this.

Answer (score 0):

WebForms was created to make it easy for WinForms developers to move to web. ASP.Net MVC's main benefits are that it separates out the Model (data), View (HTML,CSS,jQuery) and Controller (logic and routing). This allows different people to work on different parts if needed (separation of concerns). It also is much closer to a true web model, designing using HTML directly rather than this being abstracted away by ASP.Net User Controls. Obviously, in MVC, you have the HTML helpers and can make your own custom helper extensions as well as using DisplayFor and EditorFor templates.

The bosses argument is that many developers will know ASP.Net but not MVC, so it will be easier for others to work on it. However, MVC has been out a while now and many keen developers will have already picked this up or can do very quickly. It's a very clean and powerful way to develop web applications very quickly and easily maintainable in my opinion. ASP.Net of course has its advantages too but you asked "what makes MVC superior" so I've just argued a few benefits of MVC over ASP.Net. This is by no means an exhaustive comparison and hopefully others will add their opinions too.

Answer (score 0):

I would search data or survey result showing superiority of MVC projects rather than telling him how good MVC is. MVC is just more productive way of creating & maintaining quality software. One thing I would like to add is that since UI is completely decoupled with biz logic, it is a lot better to automate code production with code generation tools such as T4 and MVCScaffolding.